# Do new ADODB recordSet's create a new connection?

Tags: vb.net, ado, adodb

I want to avoid creating multiple concurrent connection and I can't figure out how to tell what's going on behind the scenes.

Ex.

```
Sub TestConnections()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim qry1 As String
    Dim qry2 As String
    Dim rs1 As New ADODB.RecordSet
    Dim rs2 As New ADODB.RecordSet

    conn = New ADODB.Connection

    conn.ConnectionString = "<insert connection details>"

    conn.open(conn.ConnectionString)

    qry1 = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable;"
    qry2 = "SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable;"

    rs1.Open(qry1,conn)
    rs2.Open(qry2,conn)

End
```

Do I have two open connections right now, or are the two open record sets sharing the same connection?

Comment: They will be sharing the same connection, and holding 2 recordsets for different queries.

Comment: Perfect, if you post that as an answer I can accept it and close out the question.

Comment: Sure, added some more info too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be sharing the same connection, and holding 2 record sets for different queries.

The reason for this is because the connection object is the actual connection that the query gets sent across, and since it's the same object passed, it's the same connection that will handle both queries, although the recordset is returned and stored into the different variables.